# time series correlation using dynamic time warping(DTW) in python

Tags: python, r, statistics, dtw

here is my three time series:

```
t1  t2  t3
3   8   17
1   8   18
0   8   17
0   8   18
2   8   17
3   8   17
0   8   18
0   8   17
2   8   17
3   8   18
1   8   17
0   8   17
0   8   17
1   8   17
2   8   16
2   8   16
3   8   16
0   8   16
2   8   16
2   8   16
3   8   16
1   8   17
1   8   16
2   8   16
3   8   16
1   8   17
2   8   16
4   8   17
0   8   16
1   8   17
3   8   16
0   8   16
3   8   16
2   8   16
2   8   17
0   8   16
2   8   16
2   8   17
3   8   16
3   8   16
3   8   16
2   8   16
4   8   16
1   8   16
0   8   17
0   8   17
2   8   17
1   8   17
2   8   17
2   8   18
0   8   18
1   8   18
0   8   17
0   8   17
2   8   17
1   8   17
2   8   17
0   8   17
0   8   17
0   8   17
```

as i have seen , DTW  can give us output , which can tell us a similarity between time-
series

but i don't know how can we do that?

how can we say that with the output of DTW?

which distance is good ?? high or low?

help me to solve this problem

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged R? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

With use of [DTW](https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/dtw.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from dtaidistance import dtw

data = StringIO("""
t1   t2   t3
3   8   17
1   8   18
.   .   .
.   .   .
0   8   17
0   8   17
""")

# load data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='   ', engine='python', dtype=float)
# transpose data
transposed_matrix = df.values.transpose()
# calculate series cost
results = dtw.distance_matrix_fast(transposed_matrix, compact=True)
```

**Output:**

Cost results for comparing 3 time series. Lower cost is better.

```
[ 51.4392846  118.73078792  67.71262807]
```

Comment: @jony in return you get condensed distance matrix with contains results calculated based on single distance matrix for each pair of data. I think the results say that `t1` has best correlation with `t2` and `t3`

Comment: i have one more question -: if one series is in between (1,20) and second (600,700). can we still apply DTW on this data for finding relation between them?

Comment: @jony You can re-interpolate the shorter one to be the same length as the longer.

Comment: and more distance is better or less??

Comment: @jony `more distance = more data` for interpolation

Comment: i meant to say, if i get distance in between (t1 and t2 = 100) , (t1 and t3 = 250)(total data points same ) , now which one is better!

Comment: @jony first one pair has better correlation `100<250`